# C# Selenium fails to correctly assert

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

Test below fails, saying that `xpath` expression is not correct. I did it according to online tutorials.

```cs
// open browser
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
// navigate to site
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://localhost:44311/");

// identify details button
IWebElement detailsLink = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'Details')]"));

// operation
detailsLink.Click();

var detailsLabel = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text() = 'Change in $'"));

// assertion
Assert.That(detailsLabel.Displayed);
```

I want to create simple Selenium test.

- I'm pressing specific button to open new page
- Checking if specific object is loaded correctly on that page

Button is `<a></a>` with `Details` inside. There are actually duplicates of that, the only unique thing is `href`. This might be the first issue, but I don't know how to "catch" it.
`detailsLabel` is actually a `<div>Change in $</div>` with `class` that I think is irrelevant to the tests.
So, my question is, how to write this test correctly? Test itself should be more or less fine, but `detailsLink` and `detailsLabel` has certain issues.

Edit

```cs
IWebElement detailsLink = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='Details?cryptocurrency=BTC']"));

//operation
detailsLink.Click();

var detailsLabel = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Change in $')]"));
```

Return exception `Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException` for `detailsLink`

Edit

````cs
IWebElement detailsLink = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='Details?cryptocurrency=BTC']"));

detailsLink.Click();

var detailsLabel = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Change in $```
Test fails at `detailsLabel`, fails to find our target `div`.
````

Comment: Once click on `detailsLink` is it navigates to new url or opening a new browser window?

Comment: @KunduK it successfuly opens web browser, moves to `detailsLink`, and fails to find the `div`.

Comment: @Have you provided enough wait to identify the element?

Comment: @KunduK just found out that there is no need to ask, because Firefox allows copying of XPath to any element. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate if `//*[contains(., 'Details')]` `xpath` is unique you can do something like

```
List<WebElement>list = webDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'Details')]"));
```

now, if `list` is empty - this means your locator is wrong and if it contains more than 1 element your locator is not unique.
But the better way is to validate this manually and directly on the webpage with `F12` `Inspector` tool on your browser.
To locate the element containing some `href` without the specific href text use `//href` in case `href` is an element tag. Otherwise use `//*[@href]` if `href` is an attribute.
For the `detailsLabel` try using `//div[contains(text(),'Change in')]` `xpath`
I used `Java` syntax, but it's similar enough to `C#`

Comment: Fails on first one. `Given xpath expression "css=a[href*='Details?cryptocurrency=BTC']" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.` I have managed to find direct solution thanks to your clues, but it failed.

Comment: Try using `contains` instead of exactly `=` equation. `//a[contains(@href,'Details')]`

Comment: I think i have already fixed it, but now it gives me exception. Check main post.

Comment: You need to add some delay before getting and clicking that element. read about `Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException`. That means the element was changed between the moment you performed the `detailsLink = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[href*='Details?cryptocurrency=BTC']"));` and the `click()` on it.

Comment: I did it, but it appears everyone and their mom uses Selenium in Java.

Comment: Looks like you are working with dynamic DOM site...

Comment: Ok. I finally understand the point of Selenium. You don't have to do anything, because clicks are done by Selenium itself. Silly me. But, now it fails on `detailsLabel` element not found.

Comment: I will if no one else responds, because 2nd part of the problem still persists.